# How to regex different opening hours formats?

Tags: java, regex, datetime, datetime-format

in my DB I have several Opening Hours formats:

```
Mo, Di, Do, Fr 10:00-19:00, Mi 09:30-19:00, Sa 10:00-18:30
Mo-Fr 10:00-18:00, Sa 10:00-15:00, So 11:00-17:00
Mo - Fr 10:00 - 19:00, Sa 10:00 - 18:00
Mo-Mi 9:30-20:00, Do-Sa 9:30-22:00
Mo-Sa 09:00-20:00
```

What I want to do is to regex this formats which next I will be able to store in list or map.
The main reason is to transfer this objects to new Table which is so defined with example entries:

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
| ID | ENTITY | DAY_OF_WEEK | OPEN  | CLOSE | CREATED | UPDATED |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 1 <FK> |           1 | 36000 | 72000 | <date>  | <date>  |
|  2 | 1 <FK> |           2 | 28800 | 43200 | <date>  | <date>  |
|  3 | 1 <FK> |           2 | 50400 | 72000 | <date>  | <date>  |
+----+--------+-------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
```

What I want to get from actuall format is maybe a map `Map<String, List<String>>` where key will be opening hours and value will be list of string days.

Comment: I dont think you need regex. It would be better to parse with SImpleDateFormat them to some kind of date object and then to parse in another object.

Comment: But I'm not sure will I be able to obtain which opening hours are corresponding to which day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can remove all spaces with

```
s.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Then you can split the string by a comma precceeded by a digit:

```
s.split("(?<=\\d),");
```

Then for each element of the array which you get on the previous step you can split the information into a part with days and a part with hours by using this regex:

```
(.*?)(\d{1,2}:\d{2})-(\d{1,2}:\d{2})
```

Group 1 will contain days, group 2 - opening hours, group 3 - closing hours.
Then you can try to analyze the part with days:

- If it contains a comma, then split by comma and you'll get the list of days
- If it contains a `-`, then split by `-` and you'll get a starting and a ending day of the week

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly that what I was looking for :) God bless people which know how to build regex..